# how to preview input form of a modal in another modal before submit in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have 2 modal the first modal is to display the input form, and the second modal is to preview data that has been entered on the first modal before submission.

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form action="" method="POST" name="form3">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title text-left" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Start Swap</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">            
                    <div class="widget" id="swap">
                        <div class="col-md-12 mt-20 mb-20">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <h5><i class="fa fa-arrow-up fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #8dc6fb"></i> SEND</h5>
                                    <select class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow show-tick form-control" id="currency_send"
                                        name="currency_send" title="select" required onchange="past(this)">
                                        <!--<option value="">--- select ---</option>-->
                                        <option value="1" selected="selected" data-content="<img src='../img/xe_icon/BTC.png' width='30' height='30' class='imgrs'><span> Bitcoin</span>">Bitcoin</option>
                                        <option value="4" data-content="<img src='../img/xe_icon/ETH.png' width='30' height='30' class='imgrs'><span> Ethereum</span>">Ethereum</option>                                                   
                                        <option value="2" data-content="<img src='../img/xe_icon/PM.png' width='30' height='30' class='imgrs'><span> Perfect Money USD</span>">Perfect Money USD</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <br><br>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i></span>
                                            <!--<input type="number" name="se_amt" placeholder="Amount in USD" class="form-control" id="b1" value="" onKeyUp="(this.value - (this.value/100)*2)" required> -->
                                            <input type="number" step="0.01" pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)?" title="Only numbers are allowed" name="se_amt" placeholder="Amount in USD" class="form-control" id="b1" value="" onKeyUp="mySend()" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <p id="send_crypto"></p>
                                    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 text-center" style="margin: auto; text-align: center;"><i class="fa fa-exchange fa-2x"></i></div>
                                
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <br class="visible-xs">
                                    <h5>RECEIVE <i class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #5cb85c"></i></h5>
                                    <select class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow show-tick form-control" id="currency_receive"
                                        name="currency_receive" title="select" required onchange="copyed(this)">
                                        <!--<option value="">--- select ---</option>-->
                                        <option value="1" data-content="<img src='../img/xe_icon/BTC.png' width='30' height='30' class='imgrs'><span>  Bitcoin</span>">Bitcoin</option>
                                        <option value="4" selected="selected" data-content="<img src='../img/xe_icon/ETH.png' width='30' height='30' class='imgrs'><span> Ethereum</span>">Ethereum</option>
                                        <option value="5" data-content="<img src='../img/xe_icon/XRP.png' width='30' height='30' class='imgrs'><span> Ripple XRP </span>">Ripple XRP</option>
                                        <option value="6" data-content="<img src='../img/xe_icon/TRON.png' width='30' height='30' class='imgrs'><span> Tron TRX</span>">Tron</option>
                                        <option value="2" data-content="<img src='../img/xe_icon/PM.png' width='30' height='30' class='imgrs'><span> Perfect Money USD</span>">Perfect Money USD</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <br><br>
                                    
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i></span>
                                            <input type="number" step="0.01" pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)?" title="Only numbers are allowed" name="re_amt" placeholder="Amount in USD" class="form-control" id="c1" value="" onKeyUp="myRecieve()" required>
                                        </div>                                                            
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <p id="recieve_crypto"></p>
                                    <script>
                                    
                                        function copyed(b){
                                            var bx = b.options[b.selectedIndex].value;
                                            if(bx==1){
                                                document.getElementById("crypto_address").innerHTML = "BTC Address";
                                            }
                                            if(bx==2){
                                                document.getElementById("crypto_address").innerHTML = "PM Account No.";
                                            }
                                            if(bx==4){
                                                document.getElementById("crypto_address").innerHTML = "ETH Address";
                                            }
                                            if(bx==5){
                                                document.getElementById("crypto_address").innerHTML = "XRP Address";
                                            }
                                            if(bx==6){
                                                document.getElementById("crypto_address").innerHTML = "TRX Address";
                                            }
                                            //return bx;
                                        }

                                        function mySend() {
                                            var x = document.getElementById("b1").value;
                                            document.getElementById("c1").value = (x - (x/100)*2).toFixed(2);
                                        }
                                        function myRecieve() {
                                            var y = document.getElementById("c1").value;
                                            document.getElementById("b1").value = Math.round(+((y/100)*2) + +y).toFixed(2);
                                        }
                                    </script>
                                    
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class=" input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i>
                                            <span id="crypto_address">ETH  Address</span> </span>
                                            <input type="text" name="cryp_address" id="cryp_address" minlength="8" onkeyup="checkLen(this.value)" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter address to recievve coin" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="counterDisplay" class="text-danger pull-right" style="font-size: 12px"></div>
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        function checkLen(val){
                                            if(val.length<9){
                                                document.getElementById('counterDisplay').innerHTML = 'Invalid Entery!';
                                            }
                                            if(val.length>8){
                                                document.getElementById('counterDisplay').innerHTML = ' ';
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </script>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" id="exbutton" class="btn btn-primary" name="preview_order" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#prvwModal" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-refresh" id="resh" aria-hidden="true"></i> Preview Order</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When you click on preview it displays the next modal

```html
<!-- preview Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="prvwModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="prvwModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="prvwModalLabel">Preview Oder</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <h3><?php 
                    if(($_SESSION['currency_receive'])==1){
                        echo $_SESSION['re_amt']." BTC";
                     }elseif(($_SESSION['currency_receive'])==2){
                        echo $_SESSION['re_amt']." PM";
                     }elseif(($_SESSION['currency_receive'])==4){
                        echo $_SESSION['re_amt']." ETH";
                     }elseif(($_SESSION['currency_receive'])==5){
                        echo $_SESSION['re_amt']." XRP";
                     }elseif(($_SESSION['currency_receive'])==6){
                        echo $_SESSION['re_amt']." TRX";
                     }else{
                         echo "Invalid Selection";
                     }
                     ?>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <?php echo $_SESSION['currency_receive'].'<br>'; ?>
            <?php echo $_SESSION['currency_send']." Send<br>"; ?>
            
            <?php// echo $_SESSION['re_amt']; ?>
            <?php echo $_SESSION['se_amt']; ?>
            <?php //echo $_SESSION['cryp_address']; ?>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the PHP code I used is storing those data in sessions but if I try to carry out another transaction it still displaying the previously saved session data

```
<?php
                    //Swap Action
                    if(isset($_POST['preview_order'])){
                        $currency_send = $_POST['currency_send'];
                        $se_amt = $_POST['se_amt'];
                        $currency_receive = $_POST['currency_receive'];
                        $re_amt = $_POST['re_amt'];
                        $cryp_address = $_POST['cryp_address'];
                        if($currency_send != "" && $currency_receive !="" && $se_amt!="" && $re_amt!="" && $cryp_address!=""){
                            //condition is met open the preview modal
                            $_SESSION['currency_send'] = $currency_send;
                            $_SESSION['currency_receive'] = $currency_receive;
                            $_SESSION['se_amt'] = $se_amt;
                            $_SESSION['re_amt'] = $re_amt;
                            $_SESSION['cryp_address'] = $cryp_address;

                            //echo "<script>$('#thankyouModal').modal('show')</script>";
                            
                            //Code Review
                            //Call ANOTHER MODAL TO PREVIEW ORDER BEFORE SUBMISSION
                        }
                    }
                ?>
```

I just want the input data on the first modal to dynamically display on the preview order modal box anytime the preview order button is clicked. thank you for your contribution.

Comment: Is your both  modal on same page ? Also , did you tried this using js/jquery ?

Comment: yes, both modal is on thesame page. and I tried using js/jquery

Comment: Your session will show correct values after page refresh . Other way : You can redirect to another page and  open modal there or use js/jquery to get value from modal first and show in modal second.

Comment: please how can i do that

Comment: redirect to another page inside your php code and on page load just open second modal and if you need to go with js/jquery show your attempts then i can help you if you are facing any errors.